# CSS: How to specify a min-width on a table?

Tags: css

I have a table that is supposed to take up `100%` of the width, but when I shrink my browser window, I also need it to obey a `min-width`. However, applying a `min-width` on the table has no affect (viewing in the latest version of Safari).

How can this be done?

```
<table width="100%" style="min-width:800px">...</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the min-width on a container `div`.

Also note: min-width can be specified for `td` elements.